# Why is this assignment illegal in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, type-parameter

I'm sure I'm probably missing something fairly obvious here, but is there a reason why:

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

is allowed, but:

```
ArrayList<T extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

is not?

Comment: `T` is a real type, you already introduced it before. So this is like writing `ArrayList<Integer extends Number>` which makes little sense, it would just be `ArrayList<Integer>`. I.e. the fact that `T` has to `extends Number` has to be established before already, when you originally declared `T`, for example when you started the file `public class Foo<T extends Number> { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, with:

```
ArrayList<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); //OK
```

you are defining the concrete object of type `ArrayList` generalized with *upper bounded wildcard* `<? extends Number>`.

Type of your wildcard will match any sub-type of `Number`, which means that you can assign to your `list` variable, any `ArrayList` specialized with *any* type which extends `Number`:

```
list = new ArrayList<Float>(); //will work fine
list = new ArrayList<Double>(); //will work fine
list = new ArrayList<String>(); //will NOT work as String does not extend Number
```

*The only caveat is the [Capture Problem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html). You won't be able to add Number extender instances in your list.*

---

In here, however:

```
ArrayList<T extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); //Syntax error
```

you have a syntax error in your object declaration. You are using *bounded type parameter* to declare your variable; however, bounded type parameter is used to define a generic class/type or generic method.

Type parameter `T`, or any (preferably capital) letter, is used to declare a [generic type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) when you define your class (or method).

For example, your upper-bounded generic type in this definition:

```
public class YourClass<T extends Number> {
....
}
```

will become a real type, at run-time, when you will declare your `YourClass` type by providing some real type, as a generic type argument, like this:

```
YourClass<Integer> ints; //will work fine
YourClass<Double> doubles; //will work fine
YourClass<Float> floats; //will work fine
YourClass<String> strings; //will NOT work, as String does not extend Number
```

Pay attention, that here as well, `T extends Number` matches any type that extends `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a generic type class like T you need to explicitly declare it in your class. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) you can find official documentation.

If you want to use an unknownk wildcard class instead, you can use if freely in you code as mentiond [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/wildcards.html)

Anyway, you can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908915/java-generic-class-and-wildcards)

Answer (score -2):

generic class in java should look like this

```java
/**
 * Generic version of the Box class.
 * @param <T> the type of the value being boxed
 */
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

so you can use something like `ArrayList<T> arr = new ArrayList<T>()`

source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html